# How to add a node in nginx.conf?

Tags: nginx

I'm a nginx module developer, I want to add a new node in nginx.conf at

```
http {
    server {
        listen          80;
        server_name     www.linuxidc.com;

        ## here add a new node 
        which_idc_belongs aa;

        ...

    }
}
```

to provide a pretty API for user to add some

Would you pls give me some advice ，or there are some policies in nginx can make it.

Thank you!

Comment: Look at a example project which does the same thing. Here is one for your reference https://github.com/anomalizer/ngx_aws_auth

Comment: Ok, it would help me! Thx